# Angular Material Flex Attribute and Property not being Converted to Associated Class in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, angular-material

I woke up to a wonderful surprise this morning.  The flex attribute is no longer working in Chome (working as expected in FF, Safari and IE however).

The following markup:

```
<span flex="true"></span>
<div layout="column" flex="75" class="layout-column"></div>
```

typically gets converted to:

```
<span class="flex" flex="true"></span>
<div layout="column" flex="75" class="layout-column flex-75"></div>
```

It would appear that the intended behavior converts the flex attribute and property to an associated class.  This appears to no longer be working in Chrome.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

It looks like a new version of Chrome was released last night.  I think it may have been a breaking change.

**Additional Info:**

- Angular Material: 1.1.5
- Chrome: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)